# How high in altitude could a fog reasonably exist?

Tags: planets, weather

Background:

I am designing an RPG world where the main characteristic is that a large fog has covered the entire fantasy planet. At the time the fog was released it was a mutating killer fog that drove the what part of the civilization to the mountains, where they have lived for thousands of years and reverted back to a renaissance level fantasy world. The some of the fog mutations because fantasy races like Elves and Dwarves, and monsters too.

At the start the fog was accident of a more advanced civilization then we are currently. In essence it was nanorobots that broken free, consuming and mutating everything in their path, that once the reproduced enough they began showing up as the fog. Over time the processing power died out and they became dormant, yet even tho they became dormant, there still was so many they were visible.

These dormant nano-biomechanical-organisms will later become the magic system. Granted because they came from advanced creation of the regular physics the magic system will not just bend the laws of physics either, so preferably

Question:

Given the fog in the background, how high in altitude could it reasonably reach to cover the entire planet, such that weather in all its extremes would not overly change the amount of fog?

I would like to drive the populations up at least 2000 feet, so they are occupying just the side of mountains, but if 1000 feet or even 500 feet is more reasonable it would be good to know.

My goal is to make it so the populations do not know what the ocean is, require zeppelins to travel between mountain ranges, last a few thousands years so the population has to revert to renaissance technology and basically avoid everything below the fog layer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read the excellent Wikipedia article?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fog

Answer (score 2):

Clouds form from sea level up to the limit of the troposphere (around 9000 meters on Earth).

Fog is "just" a cloud forming close to the ground, so this pretty much answer your question: up to the limit of the troposphere.

Answer (score 2):

Since your fog is made of weird little particles, you do not have to have it follow the rules of ordinary water vapor fog.  In fact for your story it might be better than you not.  If you have the fog be like a pool of acid then that is all it can be.  People can fall in, but as a narrative device it is limited.  But if your fog is an intermittent threat then action can take place in the dangerous fog lands.

Real fog can show up lots of places on the surface.  To make your world work your deadly fog does not need to be there constantly, all the time.  It can show up and then leave, like regular fog does.  In between these nanites constituting the fog go into (mysterious!)pockets underground.  It would still have the effect of making the lowlands unliveable.

That way you could have weather change the fog - moving it along, possibly lifting it to altitude (dangerous!).  Sunny dry weather might make fog pockets more visible, or less likely.  Remaining in the lowlands for more than a day or two is suicidally dangerous because of the likelihood of fog emerging.  Do your characters dare enter?  And if they do, what strange things will they find have learned to coexist with the fog?